# Building python2 snap with snapcraft, python setup.py egg_info error

Tags: python, packaging, snap

EDIT: It seems that the setup.py purpose is to produce a package for Mac OSX with `py2app`. So the question is now: How do I prevent the snapcraft python plugin to call setup.py?

I am trying to create a snap for a python app, both to learn snap, and because this application only exists as a 14.04 deb package, which won't install on my more recent system. Notice I'm quite new to python and totaly new to snaps...

The app is Iramuteq, from [iramuteq.org](http://www.iramuteq.org/)

The existing deb package `control` file looks like this:

```
Source: iramuteq
Standards-Version: 0.1.8
Section: science
Priority: extra
Maintainer: Pierre Ratinaud <ratinaud@univ-tlse2.fr>
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 7)
Homepage: http://www.iramuteq.org

Package: iramuteq
Architecture: all
Depends: python (>= 2.7), r-base (>= 3.0.0), python-wxgtk2.8 (>= 2.8), python-xlrd (>= 0.6), python-ooolib, r-cran-rgl (>= 0.79)
Description: Interface de R pour les analyses multidimensionnelles
```

So, as I understand it, I need some python libraries, and I should embed r-cran-rgl package.

Here is the `snapcraft.yaml` file I came up with:

```
name: iramuteq # you probably want to 'snapcraft register <name>'
version: '0.7-alpha2' # just for humans, typically '1.2+git' or '1.3.2'
summary: R INTERFACE for multidimensional analysis of texts and questionnaires # 79 char long summary
description: |
  IRAMUTEQ is a GNU GPL (v2) licensed software that provides users with
  statistical analysis on text corpus and tables composed by individuals/words. 
  It is based on R software and on python language.
grade: devel # must be 'stable' to release into candidate/stable channels
confinement: devmode # use 'strict' once you have the right plugs and slots

apps:
  iramuteq:
    command: iramuteq

parts:
  iramuteq:
    source: http://www.iramuteq.org/git/iramuteq
    source-type: git
    plugin: python
    python-version: 'python2'
    python-packages:
      - ooolib
      - xlrd
      - wxgtk2.8
    stage-packages:
      - r-base # (>= 3.0.0)
      - r-cran-rgl  #(>= 0.79)
```

Running `snapcraft`, I get the following error:

```
Processing /home/franck/iramuteq/snap/parts/iramuteq/src
  Link is a directory, ignoring download_dir
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    warning: no directories found matching 'doc/_static'
    warning: no directories found matching 'doc/_templates'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dSYM' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dSYM/*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*__pycache__*' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching 'examples/*/build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'examples/*/dist'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'examples/*/*/build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'examples/*/*/dist'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'examples/*/*/*/build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'examples/*/*/*/dist'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-9UlL_H-build/setup.py", line 21, in <module>
        setup_requires=['py2app'],
      File "/home/franck/iramuteq/snap/parts/iramuteq/install/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/home/franck/iramuteq/snap/parts/iramuteq/install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 317, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "/home/franck/iramuteq/snap/parts/iramuteq/install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 372, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/home/franck/iramuteq/snap/parts/iramuteq/install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 851, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "/home/franck/iramuteq/snap/parts/iramuteq/install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1123, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/home/franck/iramuteq/snap/parts/iramuteq/install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1135, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/home/franck/iramuteq/snap/parts/iramuteq/install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 440, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/home/franck/iramuteq/snap/parts/iramuteq/install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 674, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "/home/franck/iramuteq/snap/parts/iramuteq/install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 700, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "/home/franck/iramuteq/snap/parts/iramuteq/install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 881, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "/home/franck/iramuteq/snap/parts/iramuteq/install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1120, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "/home/franck/iramuteq/snap/parts/iramuteq/install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1108, in run_setup
        raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: This distribution is only supported on MacOSXdistuitls error.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-9UlL_H-build/
```

Now, I'm stuck with distutils error... and I'm also unsure if R will (should?) be embedded into my snap, or installed on my main system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have declared `plugin: python` so sure snapcraft with try to run `setup.py`. Use another plugin, like `make` if that project has a `Makefile`. BTW, `make` is to run basically `make; make install`

However, before doing this, check the `debian/rules` file which is the makefile for Debian source package. See how they really made the previous build.

**Update:** I just checked the `debian/rules` file, it contains manual install commands.

Options that may work for your case:

1. `dump` (or DEPRECATED `copy`) plugin.
2. Otherwise, help the upstream project to make `setup.py` works for GNU/Linux too or add a `Makefile` .
3. (Could be best choice) Use any plug you like with custom commands for: `prepare:`, `build:` & `install:` from [Plugins - Common keywords](https://snapcraft.io/docs/reference/plugins/common)

It is recommend to include all needed binaries (like R) so it will not break on updates and when strict confinement applied.

To answer:

> When first run, the application installs R plugins using R own package
>   system. Can this be handled with Snap ?

Yes.

- If those packages are well defined on build, option 2 & 3 allows to use R command to install and include them in snap package.
- If those packages could be only installed on runtime, then set R to use 
  [`SNAP_COMMON` or `SNAP_DATA`](https://snapcraft.io/docs/reference/env) which are writable after deployment. snap will mount the core as read only.

There may be other options, I'm still digging to understand how snap works.

Comment: Secondary question: when first run, the application installs R plugins using R own package system. Can this be handled with Snap ?

Comment: @alci, I update my answer.